# Remove selected node removes all treenodes?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I want to remove one node from the tree when I select it.
When I select a node, my code removes it from the tree. So far so good.  But then the selection passes to the next node, so my code removes that too. And keeps going until all the nodes are gone.
I have tried using .nodemouseclick instead of .afterselect but that doesn't work right: if I select a node then another node, it removes the first node.

```
Private Sub tree_Selected_RemoveNode(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tree_Selected.AfterSelect
    Dim ActiveNode As TreeNode
    ActiveNode = tree_Selected.SelectedNode
    If Not ActiveNode Is Nothing Then
               tree_Selected.Nodes.Remove(ActiveNode)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't worked out your logic yet,  You are using the AfterSelect event, so naturally after you remove a node, the TreeView will find another node to make the active node, and this will make your code run again.  It's not clear what logic you wanted to only remove one node.  Nodes generally shouldn't disappear when a user is selecting it.  Maybe a right-click context menu with a remove menu item would be a better choice.

Comment: I have two treeviews, one where the user can select multiple nodes (I have cheated here and set each node to appear as if it is selected using colours) they can also deselect a node by clicking it again. The second treeview just has a list of items which appear selected in the first view. So I want the user to be able to click an item in the second view and make it disappear from that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do here with the user interface, but one way to avoid having all of the nodes disappear would be to remove the AfterSelect handler and add it back in when your code completes:

```
Try
  RemoveHandler tree_Selected.AfterSelect, AddressOf tree_Selected_AfterSelect
  Dim ActiveNode As TreeNode
  ActiveNode = tree_Selected.SelectedNode
  If Not ActiveNode Is Nothing Then
    tree_Selected.Nodes.Remove(ActiveNode)
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error")
Finally
  AddHandler tree_Selected.AfterSelect, AddressOf tree_Selected_AfterSelect
End Try
```